# How do I make an observable conditionally return a stream based on user selection?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs5

Trying to build an observable stream that will read from two sources conditionally. A file stream based on user selection, or an in-memory stream for the current session.

I have a drop down where the user can select one of the following:

```
Current  //in-memory stream contains entries (error, warning, trace, debug) as they happen for the current session
Error    //error.log file entries
Warning  //warning.log
Trace    //trace.log
Debug    //debug.log
```

Here's my setup code for my observable

```
    //save the in-memory stream as a local variable so it returns the same instance
    let current$ = this.$loggerService.applicationLog$

    this.logs$ = this.logSeveritySubject
        .asObservable()
        .startWith(this.applicationLogName) //the currently selected value
        .flatMap((fileName: string) => {
            if (fileName === "current") {
                return current$;
            }

            return this.$localStorageService.readAsStringAsync(filename).map((s) => {
                let a: any[] = s.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).filter(n => n.length > 0);
                return a.reverse();
            });
        })
        .merge(this.clearLogSubject.asObservable()) //used to reset the scan back to an empty array
        .scan((x, y) => {
            if (y === null) return [];
            return y.concat(x);
        }, []);
```

Now when a user selects a new value, I push a new log file name through the subject

```
this.clearLogSubject.next(null); //reset the scan back to an empty array
this.logSeveritySubject.next(this.applicationLogName); //read from the user selected option
```

The issue I'm having is, switching between the two streams starts to return duplicate entries (because the in-memory stream never completes perhaps?). It leads me to think that when `return current$;` runs multiple times, it actually puts the same instance into the final observable stream multiple times.

Perhaps there's a better way to code this. I basically want a user to select which log source to view from. The only caveat is that the in-memory observable never closes because it could be written to at any moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `flatMap` (alias for [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap)) that merges events from all observables that come to it hence the duplicate entries. Use [switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) instead because it uses events from last observable only.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but there's a serious lack of good examples for the RxJs library. Thanks for the answer.